# Property 'allowIDFACollection' not found on object of type '__strong id' Google Analytics iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I have implemented Google Analytic in my app,I would like to use Display Feature of Google Analytics which is explained here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/display-features#overview

I am using the same code as describe in doc

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

But its giving me the error  **Property 'allowIDFACollection' not found on object of type '__strong id'**

I have also linked the libAdIdAccess.a and AdSupport.framework,
but the error is still there

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `id tracker`, specifically the `id` part, because you aren't telling the compiler what the class type is so it doesn't know what properties are available. Make the class type specific so the compiler knows that what you're asking it to do is actually possible.

Comment: Yes wain previously when I got eroor I was not using the framework and after adding framework I have not specified the class type thats why it was giving error not its resolved

Answer (score 1):

Was doing a silly mistake..... now after adding both framework (Addsupport and adidaccess)I have update tracker object type too

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

old code

```
id tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker];
tracker.allowIDFACollection = YES;
```

Comment: But `tracker` is `nil` for me. Do we need to create it manually?

Comment: Found in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/advanced. e.g. `[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-Y"];`